# Triple integral gravitational potential between point and sphere

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-gravity, potential-energy, integration, calculus

Problem for self-study: Gravitational potential between a point $\mathbf a$ and a uniform sphere, leaving out gravitational and density constants
$$
V(\mathbf{a})=\int\int\int\dfrac{1}{\vert\mathbf a - \mathbf r\vert}d\mathbf{r},
$$
where I converted to spherical coordinates:
$$
V=\int_0^{2\pi}d\phi \int_0^{\pi}\int_0^{R}\dfrac{\sin\left(\theta\right)r^2}{\vert\mathbf a - \mathbf r\vert}d\theta dr
$$
The book gives as hint: If you put point $\mathbf a$ on the $z$-axis, you can use the cosine formula to get the distance $\vert\mathbf a - \mathbf r\vert$ based on $a,\theta,r$. Hence, I modeled the problem as:

$$
\int_0^{2\pi}d\phi \int_0^{\pi}\int_0^{R}\dfrac{\sin\left(\theta\right)r^2}{\sqrt{r^2-2a\cos\left(\theta\right)r+a^2}}drd\theta
$$

Now I guess I am doing something wrong, because whatever I am doing, I can't integrate this formula nicely, whether using $dr$ or $d\theta$ as the inside integral, nor integral calculators can figure it out. For example try on wolfram alpha:
integral r^2sintheta/sqrt(a^2+r^2-2*r*a*costheta) from theta=0 to pi from r=0 to R
and nothing will come out. Trying it in steps, it will figure something out, but never close to the simple result, which should be $2\pi(R^2-a^2/3),0<a<R$.

Can someone show me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Both angular integrals are elementary.

Comment: But doing integrals is math, not physics.

Comment: The final $0<r<R$ makes no sense. The $r$ integral has already been done, and those inequalities give the range of the radial integration. They have nothing to do with the range of validity of the formula you gave, which is $0<a<R$.

Comment: Got it, very sloppy of me, made the edit.

Comment: *nor integral calculators can figure it out.* Not true. In Mathematica 13.2, ``Integrate[Sin[t] r^2/Sqrt[r^2 - 2 a Cos[t] r + a^2], {r, 0, R}, {t, 0, Pi}, Assumptions -> {0 < a < R}]`` produces ``-a^2/3 + R^2``.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>You should rewrite the square root to take into account that $a>R\geqslant r\geqslant0$, and then</strike> make the substitution $\chi=-\cos\vartheta$, so that the whole integrand depends upon $\chi$ at only one place, and that dependence is linear. Makes it really easy to do that angular integral, and then the last integral can also be easily done.

<strike>Your simple result is definitely wrong. You cannot have any $r$ dependence in the final answer, only $R$ and $a$, and it also does not have the correct behaviour anyway.</strike>

The integral also seems wrong. I integrated the whole thing and got a result that seems nonsensical. I do not think you have the potential integral written down correctly.

EDIT: The integral over $r$ needs to be broken down into $[0,a)$ and $(a,R]$ pieces. Then it is possible to get your simple result.

Comment: Ah, you are right, $r$ should be $a$ in the final answer, for $0<r<R$. Also I added the original equation in Cartesian coordinates at the top now for comparison. Is there now an obvious mistake visible in my integral that I adapted from the original?

Comment: The adaptation is correct, the initial integral is missing a lot of stuff but can be tolerated since those are just a constant multiple away. Your quoted simple result is just plain wrong. It should just be one simple term and nothing else.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent This is a uniform density ball. The interior potential has [two terms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_potential#Spherical_symmetry) if the potential at infinite distance is zero.

Comment: @Ghoster, that I know, but why would the point mass be put inside the uniform density ball? I kinda need to know if he meant $a<R$ or $a>R$

Comment: I meant $0<a<R$

Comment: I have edited my answer to take your situation into account.